# Repeat while loop doesn't work - why?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want an imageView in my viewController to "pulsate", that means become bigger and then tinier again and repeat that until the "start"-button was pressed. The problem is, that every time I call that function in the viewDidLoad() with a repeat-while-loop, it has got a breakpoint for whatever reason.

That's the part of my viewDidLoad():

```
repeat {
   pulsate()
} while hasStarted == false
```

When I press the start button, hasStarted becomes true and it should stop pulsating. But it doesn't even start the function, it immediately calls an error. Where's the problem?

Here's my pulsate()-function

```
func pulsate()
{
    frameOR = imageView.frame
    frameNext = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.midX - 35, y: imageView.frame.midY - 35, width: 80, height: 80)
    let frameVDL = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.midX - 150, y: imageView.frame.midY - 150, width: 300, height: 300)

    if start == false
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            self.imageView.frame = frameVDL
        }) { (finished) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
                self.imageView.frame = self.frameOR
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank your for your help! Have a great day!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You are blocking the main thread. No button (or any other) UI action method will be executed before program control returns to the main event loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UIView.animate`'s built-in options to really simplify what you're trying to do, *and* avoid locking up the thread.

Give this a try:

```
let frameOR = imageView.frame
let frameVDL = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.midX - 150, y: imageView.frame.midY - 150, width: 300, height: 300)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
               delay: 0.0,
               options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse, UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat],
               animations: {
                imageView.frame = frameVDL
                },
               completion: nil)
```

Your imageView should now be in a full "pulsing" loop, without needing any additional code. When you're ready to *stop* the animation, just call:

```
imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```